# How can update mongoDB multiple Object using $lte and $gte dates with $elemMatch?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My database design is like this and wants to update all those objects whose date greater than to `"2020-02-02T00:00:00.000Z"` date and less than to `"2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z"` date. I am using `$elemMatch` but it doesn't work properly. please help.

```
 {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a8b9cc71c679e92b6d4b6"),
            "employee_id" : ObjectId("5e67dce79b12c80c18240f37"),
            "__v" : 0,
            "attandence_array" : [ 
                {
                    "stay_hour" : 0,
                    "is_on_leave" : false
                    "date" : "2020-02-01T00:12:00.000Z"
                }, 
                {
                    "stay_hour" : 0,
                    "is_on_leave" : false
                    "date" : "2020-02-02T00:00:00.000Z"
                }, 
                {
                    "stay_hour" : 0,
                    "is_on_leave" : false,
                    "date" : "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z"
                }, 
                {
                    "stay_hour" : 0,
                    "is_on_leave" : false,
                    "date" : "2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z"
                }, 
                {
                    "stay_hour" : 0,
                    "is_on_leave" : false,
                    "date" : "2020-02-05T00:00:00.000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
```

OutPut like this

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a8b9cc71c679e92b6d4b6"),
        "employee_id" : ObjectId("5e67dce79b12c80c18240f37"),
        "__v" : 0,
        "attandence_array" : [ 
            {
                "stay_hour" : 0,
                "is_on_leave" : false
                "date" : "2020-02-01T00:12:00.000Z"
            }, 
            {
                "stay_hour" : 0,
                "is_on_leave" : true
                "date" : "2020-02-02T00:00:00.000Z"
            }, 
            {
                "stay_hour" : 0,
                "is_on_leave" : true
                "date" : "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z"
            }, 
            {
                "stay_hour" : 0,
                "is_on_leave" : true
                "date" : "2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z"
            }, 
            {
                "stay_hour" : 0,
                "is_on_leave" : false,
                "date" : "2020-02-05T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/):

```
Model.update(
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a8b9cc71c679e92b6d4b6") }, 
    { $set: { "attandence_array.$[at].is_on_leave": true } }, 
    { arrayFilters: [ { "at.date": { $gt: "2020-02-02T00:00:00.000Z", $lt: "2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z" } } ] })
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying using the above query but still not updating.

Comment: @VishnuChauhan sorry, there was one unnecessary dollar sign, please try know and if it doesn't work please show me the output

Comment: My output is like : { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }

Comment: How about `nMatched`? Maybe the query part is wrong? You can try from mongo  shell first

Comment: @micki  query ruining in success block, but object not updating

Comment: @VishnuChauhan works fine on my instance (4.2). What version are you using?

Comment: Maybe use proper Date objects: `{ $gt: ISODate("2020-02-02T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z)" }`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you're guessing but you might be right, sometimes people paste dates as strings even though they keep them as ISODate, thanks